# Getting contact name as link from contact id

Tags: visualforce, force.com

I get the 18 digit id for a contact in an html table. Using the dataTable it returned the contact name as a hyperlink. I'd like to do the same on the html table so as to not introduce more view state overhead by adding a dataTable back into the mix (there are lots of tables on this page.)

This is the row:

```
<td>{!s.Key_Broker_Contact_LU_PS__c}</td>
```

where s is a query variable .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the apex:outputField to get this behavior:

```
<td><apex:outputField value="{!s.Key_Broker_Contact_LU_PS__c}" /></td>
```

Comment: Excellent. Works . I've been using outputText on several fields in the html table , totally overlooked this. Thanks !